# How can I avoid ' ' in output when parameter is sent as blank?

Tags: css, less

I had written a set of Less functions:

```
.b(@a) when (iscolor(@a))    { border:1px solid @a;}
.b(@a) when (ispixel(@a))    { border: @a;}
.b(@a; @b; @c)    { border: @a @b @c;}
```

When call the function like this

```
.b(none; ''; '');
```

I get this output:

```
border:none '' '';
```

I am looking for:

```
border:none;
```

If I use

```
.b(none; ; );
```

I get this error:

> expected ')' got ';'

I don't want to use more functions.

I am using Crunch to compile.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're several ways:

```
.b1(...)  {border: @arguments} // you can use variadic args
.b2(@values) {border: @values} // you can use "space delimited" values as a single arg

#usage {
    .b1(1px, solid, white);
    .b1(2px);
    .b2(3px dotted black);
    .b2(4px whatever);
}
```

Output:

```
#usage {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border: 2px;
  border: 3px dotted #000000;
  border: 4px whatever;
}
```

**P.S.** And "blank" arguments (just as you initially tried) will work too - you just need escaped values:

```
.b(7px, ~'', ~'');
```